# BATTERY got wet, then won't work!

Tags: battery-life

What is that little sensor for on my LG cell phone that lines up with the battery?
Went the battery got wet, it quit working.  What is that little round sticker on the battery that lines up with that sensor?  Can it be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get a replacement battery.  That's much cheaper than buying a new smartphone.

Try here:

http://www.shopandroid.com/device-selector-lg.htm